# specify which thread to run in Qt QThread

Tags: qt, qthread

well as I think the question is pretty naive! , but I couldn't find answer anywhere

the question: how to pass order to a SPECIFIC thread "thread 3 for example"

the only thing that I find getting info about threads is `QThread::idealThreadCount()` which returns 12 on my I7 3930K CPU "which is correct as 6 cores with 2 virtual threads per core"

now how to use this 12 threads .. I have 12 threads.... then what?? how to tell the thread with ID from 1 to 12 to do a specific job

edit:
assume I want to use the 12 threads,each thread will do a different QProcess

so thread 1 do process C:\process1.exe,
thread 2 do process C:\process2.exe

and so on ..., if I know the thread ID I will have full control ,

but using a subclass like `MyThread = new MyThread(QString(process));` doesn't tell me which thread is this...

Comment: You don't need to create a QThread to launch a new QProcess. QProcess already uses a separate thread.

Comment: so if I call 10 processes , each process will go to the next available thread?

Comment: A process won't use an "available" thread. A process will *create a new thread*. So if you start 10 processes, you will create 10 new threads.

Comment: seems good!! , but if all threads are busy , how will it behave? queue?

Comment: Moreover, the process can have several threads, and it usually does. The operating system schedules threads execution and gives each thread a chance to execute some code for certain amount of time. This depends on many factors like thread and proccess priority, numbers of proccessors and proccessor cores, etc.. It feels like that you actually want to assign a thread to certain proccessor core. This can be done, but it's OS-specific. For example in windows in can be done using SetProcessAffinityMask or SetThreadAffinityMask functions.

Comment: Are you talking about **"CPU thread"** or **"software thread"**? Your I7 3930K has 12 CPU threads, but it is currently managing a few *hundred* software threads. Each process creates one or more software threads. Why do you want to choose the thread?

Comment: well,shortly, the client want to launch multiple command line processes, each line at a different CPU thread "as the process is CPU hungry"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it was simpler than what I thought :) , Qt is doing all the stuff for me, so when I launch multiple threads in a loop for example , Qt checks if this thread is available for work or not, if it is available it will get called, if not then the call will get Queued

example test that worked for me using QProcess and QThread:

main of desired file to be launched in a QProcess

```
//desiredFile.exe

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int sum;
    for(int i = 0;i < 1000000000;++i)
    {
        //intensive task to keep threads busy
        sum += (i%2 == 0)? i:-i;
        sum += (i%3 == 0)? i:-i;
        sum += (i%4 == 0)? i:-i;
        sum += (i%5 == 0)? i:-i;
    }
    qDebug() << sum;
}
```

main of the multi threaded program:

```
//main.cpp
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include "thread.h"
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);


    QString path = QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath ();
    path.append("/desiredFile.exe");
    for(int i = 0;i < QThread::idealThreadCount();i++)
    {
        Thread *workerThread = new Thread(path);
        workerThread->start();
    }

    return a.exec();
}
```

and the thread code

```
//thread.h
#ifndef THREAD_H
#define THREAD_H

#include <QThread>
#include <QProcess>
#include <QString>

class Thread : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Thread(QString commandLine);
    void run();
//signals:
    //void resultReady(const QString &s);

private:
    QString CL;//commandline
};
#endif // THREAD_H


//thread.cpp
#include "thread.h"

Thread::Thread(QString commandLine)
{
    this->CL = commandLine;
}

void Thread::run()
{
    QProcess mProcess;
    mProcess.execute(this->CL,QStringList());
    mProcess.waitForFinished();
    mProcess.close();
}
```

hope this helps :)

Comment: You don't need threads for it. First - you should understand difference between **PROCESS** and **THREAD**. Second - I don't see in your samples, why you really need processes. Threads are enought.

Comment: If you're going to use QThread, unless you want to change how Qt handles threads, you should not be inheriting from QThread. See here: http://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2010/06/17/youre-doing-it-wrong/

Comment: @DmitrySazonov I tried to use processes without threads, but it wasn't working as expected "it was doing them in a sequential way not parallel" , about the example that I've written, it is just an example to test the code with a process, you can assign any process "which you didn't write like an antivirus program, which will run correctly in a separate thread as needed"

Comment: @Merlin069 I know this !! :) , but I did it this way for simplicity, as I'm not experienced about what is the required mechanism to move a QProcess to another QThread

Comment: Just do not use `waitForFinished`

Comment: I tried this, but it is still doing it in a sequential way :S